# How connect a server from inside office.js code

Tags: office-js

I am developing an office.js application. I also developed an express server which runs and wait for http request. 
But i have troubles with how to connect both part.(both codes are written with Node thecnology) 
I tried the http module in order to send post request from the office.js application to the express server in the other code, but it didnt work.
Here is the code from the office.js app:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    userid : 8888,
    username : 'excell sending info - third test'
  })



const options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 8888,
  path: '/test',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('badRequest', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
//OfficeHelpers.UI.notify();
req.write(data)
req.end()





    });
} catch (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
}
```

}

Wireshark indicated that there is a bad request. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you are working on building an Office Add-in using Office.js. The Express server that you are running locally is it running on https? As you know, as a security measure, add-ins can only be loaded using https and connect to sites/services that also https. You can see from our latest template that we have, and we also created a simple webpack-dev-server that uses https with an auto-generated dev-cert.Check out the template for examples on how to generate the cert and configure it for the server.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane

Just as a quick, random, pointer for you on Express.js, I found this blog to be helpful: https://timonweb.com/posts/running-expressjs-server-over-https/
I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you fro your answer! I followed the blog you sent to me and saw the following line to create the self signed certificate:

Comment: openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert


please where should I write this above command tin order to get it works?
I tired in the CMD and got a message saying openssl is not recognized..

Comment: Hi @LouMM

I did all the required steps and now the express server is running on https.
The issue is with the excel code. When I am trying to to access the server from my office.js apllication through https quries, it doesn't work.
What am i missing please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using HTTPS and by creating the certificates needed for it. 
Then the request could be sent correctly server.